# Backend setup for images and videos to download and use inside android app

Tags: android, server, cloud, backend, gif

I want to store some images and gifs on cloud and download to use it inside app by every user via links. I tried with firebase, it gives only 1 gb per day download limit but I want to download 50-200 gb per day because of 2-3 k users and 50-60 mb for each, which it cost 10-20 $ per day. then I tried google drive but I found that can't use it for such big bandwidth and also its links are not encrypted, if anyone get that link from app and paste it on browser then he can access that file, but firebase links don't open that it only opens asset from inside app.

So can anyone guide me, what is the best and cheapest way to achieve it considering growth in future.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution:

Using a cloud computing solution (Azure, AWS etc) or buy a hosting place. Write a small backend code for access to the links. I usually create a REST API using Slim Framework and for every call, maybe you can use an API key so that only a device with an API (your app) key can access the link.

Slim Framework: http://www.slimframework.com/
Azure: https://portal.azure.com/

[Update]
If you get hosting, you can do the following:
Set up Slim Framework on your server to create REST API. Follow the link above for documentation. Create a Database in your CPanel of your hosting and use this DB in the API to manage your data.

Comment: hi, Basu,  (Azure, AWS etc) are very expensive and will cost around 10-20$ per day, but if I get web hosting then will it do the same work , and if yes then what others actions I have to perform after buying hosting, can you please explain a little

Comment: Please check the edit. Roughly stated the process you can follow

Comment: ok, I will try and apply it, is upload vps server is good option for this? only slim framework I need to achieve the result or to do more things? can you suggest link of some tutorial for it. Thanks in advance

Comment: any hosting server will be good. check according to your need. You can try GoDaddy, digitalocean...

Comment: Here's a good article I wrote on medium which can definitely help you https://medium.com/@basu.singh/creating-rest-api-using-slim-framework-getting-started-with-server-side-scripting-848d23a987f2